# Discord js delete if message has many uppercase letter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want if message has many uppercase capital letters , bot detected this and delete.

Here my code:

```
if (msg.content.length >= 10 && msg.content.toUpperCase()) {
        msg.delete();
    }
```

But this code, delete if message has 11 words. Please help me. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get all of the uppercase letters, count the amount it finds and do your logic there.

In this example, I created a function to delete the message if the message contains more than 10 uppercase letters.

```js
const msg = "This Is a MESSAGE"
const msg2 = "THIS IS A MESSAGE"
const allowedAmount = 10

function deleteIfManyUppercase(msg) {
  const uppercaseLetters = msg.match(/[A-Z]/g)
  if (uppercaseLetters.length > allowedAmount) {
    console.log("Delete Msg", msg)
    // msg.delete()
  }
}

deleteIfManyUppercase(msg)
deleteIfManyUppercase(msg2)
```